# Minecraft Spigot Java Crashes at random times

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

- **Server Info**: Home
- **OS**: Mac 13.1.0
- **Wrapper**: Nothing but a script and the screen command.
- **Java Version** java version "1.6.0_65"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
- **Level of Access**: A friend is hosting the server and I can ssh to it.
- **Server Version**: CraftBukkit version git-Spigot-1487 (MC: 1.7.9) (Implementing API version 1.7.9-R0.3-SNAPSHOT)
- **Permissions Plugin**: GroupManager
- **Other**:

  ```
  #
  # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  #
  #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001066351f1, pid=32991, tid=9987
  #
  # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
  # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
  # Problematic frame:
  # V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2351f1]
  #
  # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
  #
  # An error report file with more information is saved as:
  # /Users/minecraftserver/Desktop/Wizoracraft_Server/hs_err_pid32991.log
  #
  # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
  #

  ./start.command: line 3: 32991 Abort trap: 6           "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" -Xmx8192M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar spigot-1.7.9-R0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar -o true
  ```

Here is a link to the log file referenced in the error message:
http://pastebin.com/2W9YEFGp

I get this error message at seemingly random times, but mostly when starting up or shortly after starting.

Comment: Although the answer to this question turned out to have nothing to do with the server plugin, that doesn't change the fact that the question is off-topic as tech support for modded minecraft, which [includes server plugins in addition to clientside mods](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13467/modded-minecraft-server-tech-support?cb=1)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because technical support for modded minecraft (client or server) is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update to java 7.0_60
https://www.java.com/en/download/

Your problem has nothing to do with spigot or minecraft it is a JRE malfunction